# Why vs code is giving 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch' ' when I already Installed the module

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, pip, pytorch

So I was trying to install PyTorch and I did the following:

`python -m venv env`

`source env/bin/activate`

Then I installed PyTorch as given in the official documentation.

`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118`

Now If run `python` in the terminal and `import torch` it runs perfecty, also if I run any file importing pytorch with terminal, or inside vs code terminal(Run Python File) it works fine.
But when I run using code runner(Run Code) it throws `MooduleNotFoundError`.

I have selected the correct Interpretor Path(/env/bin/python).

**What could be the problem here??**

Comment: is code runner running in the same terminal where you you activated your virtual environment?

Comment: maybe you have to use `pip` instead of `pip3`. Or maybe use `python -m pip ...` to make sure you run it with correct python. You may also check `python -V` and `pip -V` and `pip3 -V` to see versions.

Comment: maybe use `which python` to check `/full/path/to/python`, and later use the same `/full/path/to/python` in other tools.

Comment: @starball virtual environment  was activated from the bash terminal in linux, also the terminal inside vs code is just as same. when I click on Run Python File In Dedicated Terminal it runs the python file in the terminal doesn't shows any issue, when I click on Run Code it shows the ModuleNotFoundError (This one doesn't runs on any terminal directly show output with error as traditional vs code output)

Comment: @furas I've tried using both pip and pip3, I don't think theres any issue with version.

Comment: then run `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...` to install modules for `/full/path/to/python` which you use to run code. And when you run in code runner also use `/full/path/to/python`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code to the setting.json

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
            "python": "python3 -u",
        }
```

In fact, I think it's better to use the `Run Python File` option provided by the Python extension.

Answer (score 0):

ModuleNotFoundError => When you try to import a module that is not installed or not found in the current Python path.

An incorrect Python environment or missing path configuration can cause this error in VS Code.